# [UWP][C#]Is there a way to get coordinates(left,top Points) of Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm building a pdf viewer for UWP using C# and I'm trying to get the coordinates of the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle`.
In .net framework, `System.Drawing.Rectangle` has two properties(`X,Y`) to get top, left coordinate. I want to do the same in UWP using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [UWP][C#]Is there a way to get coordinates(left,top Points) of Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle?

You could use [`TransformToVisual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transformtovisual) to get relative coordinate for `Window.Current.Content`. For detail please refer the following code.

```
var trc = TestRect.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
Point screenCoords = trc.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
```